# How to get Bot to respond with the username?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is my first time coding seriously and I'm trying to set up my own discord bot.
I'm trying to set up a simple response system but where it will answer with the username of the author but everything I've tried has not worked. For example, if i try ${message.author} in the response it will say "hello ${message.author}! instead of giving the username. I've included what I have written so far, I'm hoping someone more skilled than me can tell me what im doing wrong.
[Basic discord bot code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I36N4.png)

I've tried ${message.author}, ${user}, ${msg.author.tag}, {msg.author.tag}, {msgauthortag}, ${user.id}, ${user.username}, {user.id}, {message.author.name}. I want the bot to respond with the name or username of the person who wrote the message.

Comment: FYI- [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must switch the apostrophes (') around the string to backticks (`). Also according to the DJS docs, to reply with the username of the user it should be [message.author.username](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User?scrollTo=username). Your code should look something like this:

```
message.reply(`hello ${message.author.username}!`)
```

For more information about template literals, you can read the Mozilla docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals